# Laravel Yajra DataTable: How to stop index column ( having row serial numbers) from changing when other columns are sorted

Tags: laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra-DataTable for Laravel 8 application. All Yajra DT features are working fine apart form one small issue. My first column is DT_RowIndex and has been added as
->addIndexColumn(). These are row serial numbers(1, 2, 3 ...). Naturally sorting is made false on this column. However when other columns are sorted, these serial numbers are also sorted along. I want this column to stay fix when table is sorted. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem. Below is the code I am using.

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
      if ($request->ajax()) 
      {
         $hospitals = Hospital::join('District', 'District.dt_id', '=', 'Hospital.dt_id')
                              ->join('Tehsil', 'Tehsil.teh_id', '=', 'Hospital.teh_id')
                              ->orderBy('District.dt_name', 'asc')->orderBy('Tehsil.teh_name', 'asc')
                              ->get(['Hospital.hl_id', 'Hospital.hl_name','Tehsil.teh_name', 'District.dt_name', 'Hospital.assessment_status']);
                            

         return Datatables::of($hospitals)
                        ->addIndexColumn()
                        ->addColumn('action', function($row){
         $btn = '<a href="/hospital/'.$row->hl_id.'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm text-center">View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
         $btn = $btn.'<a href="/hospital/'.$row->hl_id.'/edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm text-center">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
         $btn = $btn.'<a href="'.route('HospitalDeleteRoute', $row->hl_id).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete the hospital: '.$row->hl_name.'\')">Delete</a>'; 
                                  
         return $btn;
                           })
                       ->rawColumns(['action'])
                        ->make(true);
      }
    return view('hospitals.index');
   }
```

index php file

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered hospital-DT" id="tbl_hosp">
      <thead class="thead-dark" align="center">
         <tr class="th_sort_color">
            <th>S/No</th>
            <th>Hospital Name</th>
            <th>Tehsil</th>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>Assessment Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
       var table = $('.hospital-DT').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        searchable: true,
        orderable:true,
        order: [],
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
        ajax: "{{ route('hospital.index') }}",
        'columns': [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: '', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {data: 'hl_name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'dt_name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'teh_name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'assessment_status', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],
   //      'columnDefs': [ {
   //      'targets': [0,5], /* column index */
   //      'orderable': false, /* true or false */
   //   }]
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get index of row from the query, I'm use ms.sql and do this :

```
$hospitals = Hospital::select([
       DB::raw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum')
])->...
```

from there, you get rownum as index column of row and call it in your script, you can change this code "ORDER BY id ASC" to get what you want..